# store tokens in method to use in another method (no array use)

Tags: java

Sorry if there is a obvious answer and I'm not seeing it but I'm new to programming. I'm trying to use tokens from a .txt file as variables in a method but originally declared in another method. An example of line of code from txt file is:

`Lisa 0 0 0 0 464 38 1 6 31 113 298`

My code gathers data from the user and locates that name from text file and uses its data. The code that i need from the text file is the integers only.

```
public static void name(String n, Scanner NAME){
      while(NAME.hasNextLine()){
         String name2 = NAME.next();
         if(name2.equalsIgnoreCase(n)){
            System.out.println("Popularity ranking of name \"" +name2+ "\"");
            int num1=0;
            for(int i = 0; i<LS; i++){
               System.out.println(((i*10)+YEAR)+ ": " + num1);
               num1=NAME.nextInt();                     //where the tokens i need are
                                                        //serving as attention getter
            }
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Name not found");

   }

   public static void intro(){
      System.out.println("This program graphs the popularity of a name");
      System.out.println("in Social Security baby name statistics");
      System.out.println("recorded since the year 1900.");
      Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Type a name: ");
      String n = console.next();
      name(n,NAME);
      graphData(NAME);
   }
}
```

The place where I'm trying to use the tokens is the following:

```
public static void graphData(Scanner NAME){
    while(NAME.hasNextLine()){
         int num=NAME.nextInt();
         for(int i = 0;i<LS;i++){
               g.drawString("" + num,i*WIDTH,30+(num/2));  //part specifically 
               num.nextInt();                              //where im trying to use the tokens
         }
     }
 }
```

This is not the complete program, only what I feel is necessary. Note that there are four class constants (YEAR, NAME, LS, and WIDTH). They cannot be changed and I cannot use arrays in this program. 
Any thoughts on how i can go about doing it? 
I've been looking everywhere but can't find anything. I've also tried a couple of things such as rewriting were the tokens were in `names()` and applying it to `graphData()`.

Comment: You could make a class and store the variables in that class. You'd have one instance of that class per line in the file. The `graphData` method could be in that class as well, so that each thingie in tour file can draw itself.

Answer (score 0):

make graphData() graph only a single point and pass each int to graphData as its read in name()